# How to set HTML input border color without affecting other border properties?

Tags: html, css, input, border-color

If I have an input like this:

```
<input id="myi">
```

and I try and change the border color like this:

```
#myi {
    border-color: hotpink;
}
```

then the border loses it's rounded corners and the border takes on I guess an inset or embossed look (ie. the left and top is a darker color than the bottom and right).

How can I change the border color without affecting any other border properties?

Answer (score 1):

```css
#myi {
  border-color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<input id="myi">
```

Manually defining the border radius and setting the border style to solid appear to prevent the embossed effect.